# Is it possible to create and join a local network without losing internet connection

Tags: android, networking, google-glass

I am writing an Android server app that streams mjepg video using http local connection to a client (Google Glass) under the same network environment.The Glass does not support 802.1X EAP so I choose to host a portable HotSpot (teathering) on the server allowing Glass to join. Doing so gives Glass access to the local ip of the server. At this point neither the server nor Glass have internet connection (since they are connected locally with HotSpot and neither has 3G). 
My question is if  there is a better way to achieve peer to peer video streaming without having to give up the ability to connect to the internet?

Sorry in advance if what I have said above seems ambiguous. I have very little prior knowledge in networking.

==03-07-14 ==
Thanks @greenapps I have updated the question. I hope this is clearer :)

Comment: Sorry but i cannot follow you. First you state that the client has no internet connection. Then you say that you created a hotspot. Well i would think to give the client internet connection. But at the end the client still has no internet connection. And who is giving up internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Android device most probably only contains a single wifi client, and it will be unable to perform both as a teathering hotspot and also being connected to another WiFi infrastructure.

The best way to do this, is to have both you clients connect to the WiFi infrastructure instead. But as you hinted, the infrastructure network uses 802.1X EAP, and Google Glass does not support it.

So you are only left with the solution of using another WiFi infrastructure than the one you are trying to use.